# data returned by api not showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in node.js and am using [getting MEAN with Mongo, Express..](https://www.manning.com/books/getting-mean-with-mongo-express-angular-and-node-second-edition) in learning. Using postman for testing data is returned. However, when using the api i dont know what happens.The rendered page viewed becomes blank with no data rendered. The function parameters used are as written in the book referenced above. The code snippet are as shown below.
location.js

```
var renderhomePage = function (req, res, responseBody) {  
res.render('index',{
  title1: 'Bromitzvah',
  pageSection1: {
  title1: 'This Is Important',
  content1: 'Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh. Sed et dapibus nisl amet mattis, sed a rutrum accumsan sed. Suspendisse eu.',

  title2 : 'Another one',
  content2 : 'Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh. Sed et dapibus nisl amet mattis, sed a rutrum accumsan sed. Suspendisse eu.',

  title3 :'Probably Important',
  content3 : 'Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh. Sed et dapibus nisl amet mattis, sed a rutrum accumsan sed. Suspendisse eu.',
  },
  post1: responseBody });
};

module.exports.homelist = function (req,res) {
  var requestOptions,path;
  path = '/api/home';
  requestOptions = {
    url: apiOptions + path,
    method: "GET",
    json: {},
  };
   request(requestOptions,function (err, response, body) {
     renderhomePage(req, res, body);
   } );
};
```

mongodb collection snippet is as shown

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b9bff5e14fa7de5a113e765"), "title1" : "Bromitzvah", "post1" : [ { "title" : "The First Thing", "content" : "Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh." }, { "title" : "The Second Thing", "content" : "Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh." } ]
```

my schema is as follows

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var pageSectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title1: String,
  content1: String,
  title2: String,
  content2: String,
  title3: String,
  content3: String,
});

var post1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
});

var post2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title1: String,
 pageSection1:[pageSectionSchema],
 post1:[post1Schema],
 post2:[post2Schema],

});

mongoose.model('Location',locationSchema);
```

can someone assist me?

Comment: are you using `request` from https://github.com/request/request?

Comment: I am using request that i installed using npm.